# Error: Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 2 found instead

Tags: reactjs, chai-enzyme

```
it('should call setCampaignDate on click', function () {
    let spySetCampaign = sinon.spy(wrapper.instance(), 'setCampaignDate');
    let datePickers = wrapper.find('.campaign-date-tab').dive().find(Datepicker);
    assert.equal(datePickers.length, 2);
    console.log(datePickers);
    var date = new Date();

    for (let index = 0; index < datePickers.length; index++) {
      datePickers.simulate('change'); 
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(spySetCampaign.withArgs(date, 'startDate'));
    }


  });
```

I am trying to simulate my 'change' function and trying to test whether 'setCampaignDate' is called or not. The problem here is that the length of my shallow component returned by find is 2:

```
let datePickers = wrapper.find('.campaign-date-tab').dive().find(Datepicker);
```

When trying to call simulate on 'datepickers', it gives an error as below:

`'Error: Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 2 found instead.'.`

Not sure how to simulate on components having nodes greater than 1.

Answer (score 43):

The answer for multiple components without changing your code is to use the enzyme API to get the correct index of the button you want.

```
wrapper.find(Component).at(index).simulate('click');
```

With component being the name of whatever you're testing and index being the number you want.

Answer (score 12):

I think you should add `.first()`.

Something like this:

```
const selectedCompoent = Wrapper.find(exactlyComponent).first()
```

In your case:

```
let datePickers = wrapper.find('.campaign-date-tab').dive().find(Datepicker).first()
```

Comment: This worked for me in a React/Redux-thunk setup. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Problem:**
It means that when you query for '.campaign-date-tab' and 'Datepicker', finder is returning 2 elements. We can't perform any event (like click) at a time on 2 different elements.

**Solution:**
What ever the element that you want to access, make it unique.

Example: set some attribute to identify an element uniquely

```
<CampaignDateTab class="campaign-date-tab" data-test="dateTab1"/>
```

And query for it like `wrapper.find('[data-test="dateTab1"]')`

Again if CampaignDateTab component has multiple Datepicker components. Then you have to differentiate them with some class name or attribute name etc.

You can simulate an event at a time only on one element. Querying for some element should not return multiple elements.

Comment: Best solution I've found.

Seems kinda weird they don't clean up the wrapper when an additional shallow render occurs.

Comment: to check, `console.log(wrapper.debug())`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a for loop which then uses `datePickers` (array) instead of the singular datePicker.

You should be able to do:

`datePickers[index].simulate('change');`

Comment: Didn't work. TypeError: Cannot read property 'simulate' of undefined

Comment: @user3725876 that might mean that your `.find(...)` didn't actually find anything